# "Argument is not valid" error Financial.IRR C#

Tags: c#, irr

I am having trouble resolving the Financial.IRR function in C#. I know I have to provide a good guess value so that that error doesn't come, but the problem is that I don't know the inputs. They are generated based on different inputs and added to a list which is passed to the IRR function. The same inputs work in the excel IRR function.

The current array I have is this:

```
double[] array= new double[] {
            -1000000,
            12686.114456365202,
            12686.114456365202,
            12686.114456365202,
            12686.114456365202,
            12686.114456365202,
            12686.114456365202,
            12686.114456365202,
            12686.114456365202,
            12686.114456365202,
            12686.114456365202,
            0,
            0,
            ....
           //The array continues with 351 more 0s.
};

var val = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Financial.IRR(ref array, .01)
```

Excel returns a value of `-0.265712453`

Is there some other way I can prevent the error from coming?

Comment: Have you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.financial.irr?view=netframework-4.7.2

e.g. "The array must contain at least one negative value"

Comment: at least you know function is somewhere in the code, we don't see the code. so you are one step ahead.

Comment: I added my input array.